# prompt the input in the math function to print the output. But it print out the input that I fill

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggle with the code. I try to prompt the input in the math function to print the output. But it print out the input that I fill.
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M8Hh.png)
code:

```
def eval(x):
    print(x)
def eval_loop():
    import math
    print('enter anything')
    eval(input())
```

Comment: Because that's what your `eval` function does - just prints... If you were to use the built-in one, it would work as you expect...

Comment: I am just curious that  I input 1+2 the output of eval function is 3. then I  input 1+2 in the eval_loop function, the output is 1+2.

Comment: Because you call `eval(1+2)`. When passing an input, it is equivalent to `eval("1+2")`. Those are very different things. Try doing `eval("1+2")` and you will get the same result

Comment: Do you really want to use the built-in `eval` as your defined function name here?  It's not clear you'are aware of it or unintentionally.... but that's something you have to `evaluate` it first  ( pun intended~)

Comment: Thank so much everyone. Now I get it!  :)

Comment: def eval_loop():
    import math
    while True:
        eval1 = eval(input('enter anything  '))
        if eval1 == 'done':
            break
        print(eval1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define an `eval` function which is equivalent to `print`.

Then you call `eval(1+2)`. The argument is evaluated before the call: `1+2 -> 3` so the call is equivalent to `eval(3)` which is equivalent to `print(3)` so 3 is printed.

When you call `eval_loop` you then have the line `eval(input())`. So now what is called is `eval("1+2")`. Again the argument is evaluated: a string stays a string, and then you just print it...

In the first case the evaluation is not made by the `eval` rather than by the interpreter simply evaluating the mathematical expression being passed as an argument. In the second case, a string simply stays a string, and hence the difference in results.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a eval_loop function just do

eval(input())

and it works just fine with whatever you write there is no need for eval_loop

Comment: The reason for creating eval_function to output like "eval" function because I will write the loop function. If the user input the word " done," the function is ended. But I am struggle with this step. :)